# How to check if a stored procedure exists in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Please help I want to check if a stored procedure exists in my database. If it does exist, then that stored procedure should be dropped, and if it does not exist then the stored procedure should be created.

Please tell me query

This is my attempt so far:

```
try {
objData.Query = "if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects 
where id = object_id(N'[dbo].["+ ProcName+"]') 
and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1) 
drop procedure [dbo].[ "+ ProcName+"]" ; // 
objData.Query = " Drop Proc " + ProcName;
objData.Execute(); 
} catch 
{
}
```

Comment: what you have done so far ?

Comment: try
                    {
                        

                        objData.Query = "if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].["+ ProcName+"]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)drop procedure [dbo].[ "+ ProcName+"]" ;
                       // objData.Query = " Drop Proc " + ProcName;
                        objData.Execute();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }

Comment: `select * from sys.objects where type='p' and name=' **Stored Procedure name **'` this will find the stored procedure

Answer (score 7):

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[spa_Search]', N'P') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[spa_Search]
GO
```

You can check OBJECT_ID which is object identification number of a schema-scoped object.

> ```
> OBJECT_ID ( '[ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name . ]   
>   object_name' [ ,'object_type' ] )
> ```
>
> Arguments
>   ' object_name '
>   Is the object to be used. object_name is either varchar or nvarchar. If object_name is varchar, it is implicitly converted to nvarchar. Specifying the database and schema names is optional.
>   ' object_type '
>   Is the schema-scoped object type. object_type is either varchar or nvarchar. If object_type is varchar, it is implicitly converted to nvarchar. For a list of object types, see the type column in sys.objects [(Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql)
>
> **Return Types**
>  int
>  **Exceptions**
>  For a spatial index,
>   OBJECT_ID returns NULL.
>  Returns NULL on error.
>  A user can
>   only view the metadata of securables that the user owns or on which
>   the user has been granted permission. This means that
>   metadata-emitting, built-in functions such as OBJECT_ID may return
>   NULL if the user does not have any permission on the object. For more
>   information, see Metadata Visibility Configuration.

For quick view on [OBJECT_ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-id-transact-sql)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about your enviroment... But in **SQL Server 2000** you can try this BEFORE start the script for your procedure:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'P' and name = 'TheNameOfYourProcedure')
BEGIN
   DROP PROCEDURE TheNameOfYourProcedure
END
GO
```